# I have some problems with message id and a lot of mistakes

Tags: discord.js

I have a code, which is not working. I do not know how to finish it.
I need if user writing in one channel, his message sending in another, where admin can accept it or denie. So I have a lot of mistakes.

```
let rMember = message.id(message.id.get(args[0]));

const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  if (message.channel.id !== "someid") return message.delete();
  if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.delete();
  let rMember = message.id(message.id.get(args[0]));
  if(!rMember) return await message.delete() && message.reply("nope.").then(m => m.delete(3000));

  await message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});

  const co = '1';
  const a = '2';
  const b = '3';
  const c = '4';
  const d = '5';
  const e = '6';

  const prohibited = ['someid'];
  if (!message.member.roles.find(role => prohibited.includes(role.id))) return message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});

  const filter = (reaction, user) => ['' ,'', '', '', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

  const embed = new RichEmbed()
      .setTitle('nope:')
      .setDescription(`

       ${co.toString()}
       ${a.toString()}
       ${b.toString()}
       ${c.toString()}
       ${d.toString()}
       ${e.toString()}

      `)
      .setColor(0xdd9323)
      .setFooter(`ID: ${rMember}`);

  message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {

      await msg.react('')
      await msg.react('');
      await msg.react('');
      await msg.react('');
      await msg.react('');
      await msg.react('');

      msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
          max: 1,
          time: 30000,
           errors: ['time']
      }).then(collected => {

          const reaction = collected.first();

          switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
              case '':
                  message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(`${message.member} ${rMember}: **${co}**.`);
                  msg.delete()
                  break;
              case '':
                  message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(`${message.member} ${rMember}: **${a}**.`);
                  msg.delete()
                  break;
              case '':
                  message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(`${message.member} ${rMember}: **${b}**.`);
                  msg.delete()
                  break;
              case '':
                  message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(`${message.member} ${rMember}: **${c}**.`);
                  msg.delete()
                  break;
              case '':
                  message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(`${message.member} ${rMember}: **${d}**.`);
                  msg.delete()
                  break;
              case '':
                  message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(`${message.member} ${rMember}: **${e}**.`);
                  msg.delete()
                  break;
          }

      }).catch(collected => {
          return message.channel.send(`Error.`).then(m => m.delete(3000))
      });

  });

  try{
    await rMember.send(`${message.member} nope.`)
  }catch(e){
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "denie"
}
```

So this is working code, which sends embed message

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.id == "someid") {
    if (!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "role")) return await message.delete();
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content) return;
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
      .setTitle('woops:')
      .setDescription(message.content)
      .setColor(0xdd9323)
      .setFooter(`MessageID: ${message.id}`);

    await message.client.channels.get(`someid`).send(embed)
  }

  try{
  }catch(e){
  }
})
```

> (node:6544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
>   message.id.get is not a function

Comment: What (or rather who) is `rMember` meant to represent?

Comment: I wanted to change member mention to message id...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The ID and the mentions are both properties of a Message. You can't convert one to the other...

Comment: Yep, I just tried to redo code because I want to try to do something new for myself and got some problems. So I need for the command to work with message id.

Comment: I want to pass a message ID.

Comment: As the `message` parameter or a provided argument?

Comment: As message argument

Comment: So when I getting id by embed message, I want to use command, which will send pm to message author

Answer (score 0):

> I need for the command to work with[ a ]message [ID] .... as [an] argument.

To retrieve a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) by its ID, you can use the [`TextChannel.fetchMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) method. Keep in mind that it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Consider the following examples.

```js
// Attaching a 'then()' method...

const id = '189855563893571595';
const channel = message.channel;

channel.fetchMessage(id)
  .then(fetchedMessage => {
    // Use 'fetchedMessage'
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```js
// Using the 'await' keyword (async context required)...

const fetchedMessage = await channel.fetchMessage(id);

// Use 'fetchedMessage'
```

Implementing this in your command is relatively straightforward.

```js
try {
  // Stop if the argument is missing
  if (!args[0]) return await message.channel.send(':x: Provide a message ID.');

  // Define the channel to fetch the message in
  const channel = message.guild.channels.get('idHere');

  // Fetch the message
  const fetchedMessage = await channel.fetchMessage(args[0]);

  // Stop if the message doesn't exist
  if (!fetchedMessage) return await message.channel.send(':x: Invalid message ID.');

  // Insert code using 'fetchedMessage' here...
} catch(err) {
  // Log any errors from rejected promises
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `message.delete()` in two places - once after checking if the message doesn't exist *and* in your last `if` statement.

Comment: Hey there) Something wrong with this string.

`const fetchedMessage = await channel.fetchMessage(args[0]);`

Comment: Error about unknown message. So I didn't fix it. I changed `message.delete()`, but nothing.

Comment: The intended message doesn't exist then. You have to make sure you're checking if `fetchedMessage` is defined before using it.

Comment: I triyng to use !delete id(that I get with message.id from embed message)

Comment: If you're trying to delete the fetched message, use `fetchedMessage.delete()`, not `message.delete()`.

Comment: Yep, but I have error about Unknown Message. I tried to use console.log and...

`console.log('1')
  // until here

  const fetchedMessage = await channel.fetchMessage(args[0]);

  // to here
  console.log('2')`

And I get only 1 and error